# Outlook.com REST APIs - getting a token without dynamically sign-in

Tags: rest, email, outlook, outlook-restapi, outlook.com

Use-case: Emails to be sent from a web-application upon an event, as someuser@somedomain.com via MS Exchange or Outlook.com, using the [RESTful APIs exposed by Outlook.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#SendMessages). Only HTTP access allowed (=> no SMTP/IMAP).

All [documentation](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi) seems to mention that   the app has to forward users to [MSOnline](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize), sign-in and then use the authorization code sent back by MS online.

But, this won't work for a background task (=> no sign-in possible!) where a pre-built token(with some predefined scope) is necessary so that Outlook.com can be accessed via APIs to send mail as someuser@somedomain.com.

Any hints/pointers to how it could be done? Basically, automated authentication without explicitly signing in as 'someuser@somedomain.com' on the MS Online login page.

I did not find M$ documentation regarding [Outlook REST APIs](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi) to be of any great help and found it to be pretty difficult to navigate/understand. :(

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know this API in particular, but generally you have to register and get an API key to be used from your code.
This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#UsetheMailRESTAPI) mentions token you can obtain after registering your app, maybe you should try that.

Comment: @cdelmas, thanks, I did try that. Apparently, the only possible way is to register the app at Azure AD (and if need be, limit the users that can access the app, again at the Azure AD level) and then let user's sign-in to the app and thus generate a token, which again comes with a rigid 90 day expiry limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point you will have to have the user sign in to grant access to your app. So you would need to have some sort of user-facing web front end where they can do this. Once they have signed in and you've obtained an access token/refresh token, your background app should be able to use those tokens silently, without user interaction, at least until the user either revokes access or the refresh token expires.

Currently Azure (which provides the login/token functionality) does expire the refresh tokens after some time (90 days), at which point the user must sign in again to grant your app continued access.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Jason! So one truly cannot use outlook.com APIs in an enterprise solution, since one really cannot force the admin/maintainer to sign-in to the service account every 90 days (and regenerate the refresh tokens). Any plans to accommodate refresh tokens that last for a long time, as governed by the user? The use case doesn't involve a normal user but a service account (which, traditionally, will not have password expiry etc set).

Comment: My understanding is that yes, those plans are there. However I'm concerned I've misunderstood you. Outlook.com accounts aren't typically involved with an enterprise solution. Are you accessing Office 365 (Business/work accounts) or Outlook.com (personal consumer accounts)?

Comment: >> However I'm concerned I've misunderstood you. Outlook.com accounts aren't typically involved with an enterprise solution. Are you accessing Office 365 (Business/work accounts) or Outlook.com (personal consumer accounts)?

The use case is to build a mailing component, for a client of ours, with below listed constraints.

1. The client (say, somecompany.com) wants the emails to be routed via their corporate MS exchange only, 
2. The sender stamp on the outgoing emails should be "someuser@somecompany.com"
3. No SMTP/IMAP access to the exchange allowed.

[contd..]

Comment: This mailing component will be used (in background) by an enterprise system that would send out emails to external (*@[^somecompany].*) or internal (*@somecompany.com) addresses. So, we will have to 1. create one service account, "someuser@somecompany.com", 2. create an app on somecompany's Azure AD, 3. Restrict access to "someuser@somecompany.com" for the app 4. Make him sign-in and obtain the refresh token 5. Use that refresh token to generate access tokens so that mails can be sent by the mailing component. [contd ..]

Comment: Now, this flow would require 1. "someuser@somecompany.com" to sign-in to MS online page every 90 days, to regenerate the refresh token and 2. make this new token to be accessible to the mailing component, so that it can use the token and send out mails in background. 

This would not be acceptable for an enterprise solution (I mean, the obligation to sign-in every 90 days). :(  I hope I have made my use-case clear. Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks again for helping out!

Comment: First to be clear, the REST APIs only work on Office 365 or Outlook.com, not on-premises installations of Exchange. If that fits your scenario, you should look at the client credentials auth flow. In this flow you do not create a service account, you grant permissions to the app itself. The org administrator consents to the app, then you can get tokens silently. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/

Comment: @JasonJohnston Could a similar solution be used for an on-premise installation of Exchange? REST API is not available for Exchange?